# Is it possible to get view object access into view model Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, viewmodel

In my app all view model having a base view model class,I want to add few common views to all the views having view models. Is there any way I can identify the within the model what is the object of its views so I can add common child view into it

Answer (score 0):

You could define a `ControlTemplate` with `ResourceDictionary`,then put it into `App.xaml` as a `StaticResource`.

For example,the common view is a `Label`:

create a `commonLabel.xaml`:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    >

     <ControlTemplate x:Key="testcontrol">
         <Label Text="this is a common label"/>
     </ControlTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

then in your `App.xaml`:

```
 <Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
     x:Class="YourProject.App">
     <Application.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary Source="commonLabel.xaml"/>

     </Application.Resources>
 </Application>
```

then you could use in your pages.xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
     NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false"
     ControlTemplate="{StaticResource BaseTemplate}"
     x:Class="YourPage">

     <ContentView ControlTemplate="{StaticResource testcontrol}"/>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Thanks @LEO I have tried to achicnvo this using Master Content page and subclass it where ever required is it good idea?

Comment: @TarunSeera Yes,you also define a Content page as a base page,then let others subclass it.